# Perl hangs for regular users, works with sudo

Tags: sudo, perl

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and for some reason the perl command just hangs when a regular user calls it. However, if I use sudo with it, it will work perfectly. I'm thinking the perl program is trying to read/write something that regular users have no permissions to, but how can I be sure or figure out what?

The perl version I have is v5.18.2 and is 64bit.

The reason I'm asking is I'm trying to run a make that apparently uses perl (so it hangs), but if I run it with sudo, I don't have permissions to write over the files the make generates.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Edit: This is the output of `strace perl -v`. It goes on looping this chunk indefinitely.

> `execve("/apps/jas/bin/perl", ["perl", "-v"], [/* 62 vars */]) = 0
>   brk(0)                                  = 0x7fe3c41f5000
>   access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe3c207d000
>   access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
>   fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=87654, ...}) = 0
>   mmap(NULL, 87654, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe3c2067000
>   close(3)                                = 0
>   access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
>   read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\37\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
>   fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1845024, ...}) = 0
>   mmap(NULL, 3953344, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe3c1a97000
>   mprotect(0x7fe3c1c53000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
>   mmap(0x7fe3c1e52000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bb000) = 0x7fe3c1e52000
>   mmap(0x7fe3c1e58000, 17088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe3c1e58000
>   close(3)                                = 0
>   mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe3c2066000
>   mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe3c2064000
>   arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fe3c2064740) = 0
>   mprotect(0x7fe3c1e52000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
>   mprotect(0x7fe3c229d000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
>   mprotect(0x7fe3c207f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
>   munmap(0x7fe3c2067000, 87654)           = 0
>   getpid()                                = 29478
>   rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x7fe3c2094460, ~[RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fe3c1acdff0}, NULL, 8) = 0
>   geteuid()                               = 42590
>   brk(0)                                  = 0x7fe3c41f5000
>   brk(0x7fe3c4216000)                     = 0x7fe3c4216000
>   getppid()                               = 29475
>   stat("/lhome/username", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
>   stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
>   open("/apps/jas/bin/perl", O_RDONLY)    = 3
>   fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10
>   close(3)                                = 0
>   fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
>   rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
>   rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x7fe3c2094460, ~[RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fe3c1acdff0}, NULL, 8) = 0
>   rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
>   rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, ~[RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fe3c1acdff0}, NULL, 8) = 0
>   rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
>   rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL, ~[RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fe3c1acdff0}, NULL, 8) = 0
>   read(10, "#!/bin/sh\n\nDIRNAME=`dirname $0`\n"..., 8192) = 207
>   pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
>   clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fe3c2064a10) = 29479
>   close(4)                                = 0
>   read(3, "/apps/jas/bin\n", 128)         = 14
>   read(3, "", 128)                        = 0
>   --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=29479, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
>   rt_sigreturn()                          = 0
>   close(3)                                = 0
>   wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 29479
>   pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
>   clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fe3c2064a10) = 29480
>   close(4)                                = 0
>   read(3, "Linux\n", 128)                 = 6
>   read(3, "", 128)                        = 0
>   --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=29480, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
>   rt_sigreturn()                          = 0
>   close(3)                                = 0
>   wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 29480`

Comment: Please do a `make -n` (shows only what should be done, but it's not doing it) and compare the calls to perl. I doubt that perl gets called with the same arguments with sudo and without. Maybe it gets called with no arguments for normal users, in which case it would just wait on stdin so the user enters a command.

Comment: Doing a `make -n` also hangs. Perl also hangs when trying to output `perl -v` without sudo. In my top I can see it hogging ~43% of the CPU.

Comment: This is stange. Please do a `strace perl -v` to see where it hangs.

Comment: Doing an `strace perl -v` gives me an infinite loop. I've put the chunk that keeps looping in my original post. I can't really make much of it.

Comment: do a `which perl` and check that you really call `/usr/bin/perl`. From the strace it looks like you are calling `/apps/jas/bin/perl` which tries to find the right perl but finds itself, thus calling itself again and again. And sudo does not have this problem because it does not use the PATH of the normal user.

Comment: You're right. I'll try editing my PATH to have /usr/bin/ first and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich! That was the issue. I reorganized my PATH and now I am using the correct perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My system was using the wrong perl due to the way my PATH was stored. I organized my PATH and it's now working. If you're having a similar problem with another program, try checking your PATH.